# Find the value of $\int_{7/2}^{11/2} \frac{f(x)}{x} dx$.

Tags: integration

> A decreasing, continuous function $f(x)$ satisfies the following three conditions:
>
> 1. For all positive reals $x$, $f(x)>0$.
> 2. For all positive reals $t$, the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(t,f(t))$, $(t+1,f(t+1))$ has area $(t+1)/t$.
> 3. $$\int_{1}^2 \frac{f(x)}{x} dx = 2$$
>
> Find the value of $$\int_{7/2}^{11/2} \frac{f(x)}{x} dx$$

Area of the triagle is
$$\frac{1}{2}\begin{vmatrix}t+1&f(t+1)&1\\t&f(t)&1\\0&0&1\end{vmatrix}=\frac{t+1}{t}$$
$$(t+1) \cdot f(t)-t \cdot f(t+1)=\frac{t+1}{t}$$ and what next?

Comment: Hello, I was the one who posted this in AoPS! Glad to see you here. You need to divide by $t(t+1)$, then let $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x}$.

Comment: @piteer Why not mention the AoPS page if indeed you copied this from it?

Comment: $$\frac{f(t)}{t}-\frac{f(t+1)}{t+1}=\frac{1}{t}$$ for t>0

Comment: for x>0 if g(x)=f(x)/x then  g(x)-g(x+1)=1/x